# Send data from vuejs project to laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, request

I have crate two separate project, one in vuejs (with vue create project_name) and the other in laravel (with laravel new project_name). Now i want to send data from vuejs project to the laravel project. How can i do that?

Comment: Will you be able to include a code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like axios or fetch in your vuejs app to make http requests to your laravel app

(Axios docs: https://github.com/axios/axios)

(Fetch docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

I like axios

For example if you want to make a POST to your api you can do

```js
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
```

or a GET

```js
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
```

axios.get and axios.post are async functions, so you have to use the inside an async function whit await or use callbacks

Comment: If you use axios remember install it with npm ``npm i axios``. And sorry if my english isn't the best